# javascript кнопка звука

Tags: javascript

создаю игру на Canvas/Javascript. Есть кнопка звука при клике должен меняться иконка звука (вкл \ выкл).
через онклик не работает

```
var vol = true;
if (vol == true) {
    ctx.drawImage(volume, 900, 20, 35, 35);
}

if (vol == false) {
    ctx.drawImage(volume_muted, 900, 20, 35, 35);
}
volume.onclick = function () {vol=false;};
volume_muted.onclick = function () {vol=true;};
```

через клик не работает

```
volume.addEventListener("click", vold);
function vold() {
    vol = false;
}
```

но через кейдаун работает

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", vold);
function vold(b) {
    if (b.keyCode) {vol = false;}
}
```

Comment: volume видать без pointer-events или закрыт чем-то

Comment: Вставьте запускаемый сниппет, чтобы видеть проблему, так не очень из вопроса ясно

Comment: то есть не работает клик на иконку звука. При клике на volume значение vol=true меняется на false. Когда vol=true прорисовывается иконка со звуком, когда vol=false наоборот иконка без звука. Но через кейдаун работает, мне нужен по клику. Или нужно как то по другому надо реализовать ?

Answer (score 1):

Все, решил проблему работает, надо вот так через this

```
if (vol == true) {
    ctx.drawImage(volume, 900, 20, 35, 35);
    this.onclick = function () {vol=false;};
}

if (vol == false) {
    ctx.drawImage(volume_muted, 900, 20, 35, 35);
    this.onclick = function () {vol=true;};
}
```